# java copy file on network drive

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

I'm trying to copy files from a network drive to a folder, where I can access them online. A file looks like this, for example

```
\\GVSSQLVM\Lieferscheine\20011023\Volumed 5005.00000063.doc
```

which I can access in the Windows explorer, when I type this address in.

And the destination to copy the file to would be

```
C:\Program Files\jbossAS\server\default\deploy\ROOT.war\tmp\Volumed 5005.doc
```

I run into trouble copying the file with following code:

```
        String doc_dir = "\\\\GVSSQLVM\\Lieferscheine\\20011023\\";
        String doc_file = doc_dir.concat(doc.getUniqueFileName());
        File source = new File(doc_file);

        String home_url = System.getProperty("jboss.server.home.url");
        String home_dir = home_url.substring(5); // cut out preceding file:/
        String tmp_dir = home_dir.concat("deploy/ROOT.war/tmp/");
        String dest_file = tmp_dir.concat(title);
        File dest = new File(dest_file);

        try {
                input = new FileInputStream(source);
                output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }
        } finally {
            input.close();
            output.close();
        }
```

input is `null`. I read that the space character could be troublesome, and followed the advice to put the `source` for the `FileInputStream` in quotes, but then `new File` seems to screw the whole filename up into

```
c:\Program Files\jbossAS\bin\'\GVSSQLVM\Lieferscheine\20011023\Volumed 5005.00000063.doc'
```

where it seems to write the current path first, then add the given one with one backslash less; and it still doesn't find the file. 
`file.extists()` yields false.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any chance to move your code towards [copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) of Files?

Comment: Your code looks right, but you're not showing us how you are providing the path information. We need to see the code prior to your first line.  Are you putting the path info in quotes?  Also, there is a class in the JDK that makes copying of files a little easier.  It's called the Files class.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post with the paths information. No, I skipped the quotes, since with quotes `new File()` generates a strange path (adding the current path to the actually given one). @StefanFreitag: we're using Java 5, and I think copy is only available from Java 7 on.

Comment: In Windows, network drives are usually mapped to drive letters.  You might have to map \\GVSSQLVM\Lieferscheine to the M drive, to pick a drive letter at random.  Once you've mapped the network drive, java should be able to read from M: as easily as from C:.

Comment: Thank you, I mapped the network drive, which works fine. I put my path in quotes `"f:\Volumed 5005.00000063.doc"`, but still: `file.exists()` gives false. How come?

Answer (score 3):

try the following code its using [JCIF.jar](https://jcifs.samba.org/):

```
public static boolean createCopyOnNetwork(String domain,String username,String password,String src, String dest) throws Exception
{
    //FileInputStream in = null;
    SmbFileOutputStream out = null;
     BufferedInputStream inBuf = null;
    try{
        //jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords","true");
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain,username,password); // replace with actual values  
        SmbFile file = new SmbFile(dest, authentication); // note the different format
        //in = new FileInputStream(src);
          inBuf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
        out = (SmbFileOutputStream)file.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[5242880];
        int len;
        while ((len = inBuf.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(inBuf!=null)
                inBuf.close();
            if(out!=null)
                out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
    }
    System.out.print("\n File copied to destination");
        return true;
}
```